# creating summary field in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii and i'm looking for the best approach to solving my problem. I have a model that logs info and a view that displays all records. I need users to be able to view summary report. A typical sql script will look like this:

```
Select user, count(info) as info from tbl_log
```

My questiona are:

1) Do i create a new controller,view and search form and add a method that contains the search  criteria or should i use the same controller but create different action for this purpose?

2) Will i use createCommand() to specify my sql statement or is there a proper way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: i say use createCommand. Yii is very weak on those aspects. It mainly has a MVC with generated CRUD but it doesn't cover all use cases. Your option is to be creative. It's also over engineered when using the Database layer. Direct queries has much more control over things.

Comment: Thanks @DevZer0, so, should i create another action in the my logs controller or create another controller with another view to call a method that performs my search in the logs model?

Comment: do what makes you happy man there is no right or wrong in this case if you ask me. :)

Comment: Thanks! I shall return if i encounter any problems